# Jquery: Image is not appending when onchange function calls for the second time

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

Hi friends am trying to append an image to following div

```
<div id="appendimage" class="Serviceimg">

</div>
```

and having one dropdown

```
@Html.DropDownList("serviceType", ViewBag.ServiceList as List<SelectListItem>,
                                         new { name = "serviceType", id = "serviceType", @class = "form-control filterEmpty", onchange = "serviceTypeChange(this,true)"})
```

on changing of the above dropdown the image has to append the above div based on the drop-down text

following is my jquery function to append an image

```
function serviceTypeChange() {
    var typeofServiceTextAfterReplace = $("#serviceType option:selected").text().replace(/([~!@#$%^&*()_+=`{}\[\]\|\\:;'<>,.\/? ])+/g, '-').replace(/^(-)+|(-)+$/g, '').toLowerCase();
    $("#appendimage").empty().append('<img style="height:"80px; width:"80px;" src="../images/ServiceIcons/'+typeofServiceTextAfterReplace+'.png"/>');
}
```

for the first time the image is appending well, but after changing the dropdown for the second time, the image is not appending to the specified div, and which is showing like an unavailable image like the follwoing image

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q41oD.png)

Comment: You might define the `src` as a separate variable before appending the image, `console.log`ging the `src`, and then check to see if it looks proper.

Comment: it is showing well even well in the console

Comment: Hrm, that doesn't make sense. Copy the src in the browser (or from Inspecting the HTML) and paste it in another tab - should give you a clue.

Comment: the source path is showing correctly, but the image is not displaying and the image is displaying well enven when the src path copy pasted in the other tab

Comment: Can you please put you efforts in a fiddle and update here.